# How to move Terminal cursor to beginning of paragraph or Letters

Tags: python, terminal, colorama

I've made a code for a game in terminal but i'm having problem in moving cursor to beginning of the whole printed section . So that I can overwrite it a the next frame of the game. But i'm not able to move to beginning

```
import sys
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, init,Back
from random import randint
from pytimedinput import timedInput
import os
import msvcrt

def print_game():
    for cell in CELLS:
        if list(cell) == Player:
            print( Fore.MAGENTA + "i", end="")
        elif cell in Border:
            print( Fore.GREEN + "█", end="")
        elif cell in Spikes:
            print( Fore.RED + "▲", end="")
        elif cell == Finish_Point:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
        if cell[0] == X-1:
            print("")
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[50A')

def Gravity():
    if (Player[0], Player[1]+1) not in Border:
        if (Player[0], Player[1]+1) not in Spikes:
            Player[1] += 1
def Movement(key):
    if key == "d" and (Player[0]+1, Player[1]) not in Border:
        Player[0] += 1
    if key == "a" and (Player[0]-1, Player[1]) not in Border:
        Player[0] -= 1
def Jump():
    global Jump_Height, Player

    if (Player[0], Player[1]-1) in Border:
        Jump_Height = 0
    if Jump_Height != 0:
        Jump_Height -= 1
        Player[1] -= 1
    else:
        Gravity()

def Start_Menu_1():
    os.system("cls")
    print("""
            




     ______                            
     | ___ \                           
     | |_/ /   _ _ __  _ __   ___ _ __ 
     |    / | | | '_ \| '_ \ / _ \ '__|
     | |\ \ |_| | | | | | | |  __/ |   
     \_| \_\__,_|_| |_|_| |_|\___|_| 

    
    
    
    
    """)
    print( "                ",Back.WHITE + "PLAY")
    print( "                 QUIT")
def Start_Menu_2():
    os.system("cls")
    print("""
            




     ______                            
     | ___ \                           
     | |_/ /   _ _ __  _ __   ___ _ __ 
     |    / | | | '_ \| '_ \ / _ \ '__|
     | |\ \ |_| | | | | | | |  __/ |   
     \_| \_\__,_|_| |_|_| |_|\___|_| 

    
    
    
    
    """)
    print( "                ","PLAY")
    print( "                ", Back.WHITE + "QUIT")
def Lose_Menu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("""
    

    
 __     __           _                      _ 
 \ \   / /          | |                    | |
  \ \_/ /__  _   _  | |     ___  ___  ___  | |
   \   / _ \| | | | | |    / _ \/ __|/ _ \ | |
    | | (_) | |_| | | |___| (_) \__ \  __/ |_|
    |_|\___/ \__,_| |______\___/|___/\___| (_)
                                              
                                              

    
    
    
    
    
    
    """)
    input("press enter to  'Exit' ")
def Win_Menu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("""
    

    
 
 __     __                                 _ 
 \ \   / /                                | |
  \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      _____  _ __   | |
   \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / _ \| '_ \  | |
    | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V / (_) | | | | |_|
    |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ \___/|_| |_| (_)
                                             
                                             

                                              
                                              

    
    
    
    
    
    """)
    input("press enter to  'Exit' ")

init(autoreset=True)
colorama.init()

# SETTINGS

Y = 42
X = 36
Border = [
    (26, 0),
    (27, 0),
    (28, 0),
    (29, 0),
    (30, 0),
    (31, 0),
    (32, 0),
    (33, 0),
    (34, 0),
    (35, 0),
    (26, 1),
    (35, 1),
    (26, 2),
    (35, 2),
    (26, 3),
    (35, 3),
    (26, 4),
    (30, 4),
    (31, 4),
    (32, 4),
    (33, 4),
    (35, 4),
    (18, 5),
    (19, 5),
    (20, 5),
    (21, 5),
    (22, 5),
    (23, 5),
    (24, 5),
    (25, 5),
    (26, 5),
    (30, 5),
    (35, 5),
    (18, 6),
    (30, 6),
    (35, 6),
    (18, 7),
    (30, 7),
    (35, 7),
    (18, 8),
    (30, 8),
    (32, 8),
    (35, 8),
    (18, 9),
    (22, 9),
    (23, 9),
    (24, 9),
    (25, 9),
    (26, 9),
    (27, 9),
    (28, 9),
    (29, 9),
    (30, 9),
    (32, 9),
    (35, 9),
    (18, 10),
    (23, 10),
    (24, 10),
    (30, 10),
    (32, 10),
    (33, 10),
    (34, 10),
    (35, 10),
    (18, 11),
    (19, 11),
    (20, 11),
    (24, 11),
    (30, 11),
    (32, 11),
    (18, 12),
    (24, 12),
    (30, 12),
    (32, 12),
    (13, 13),
    (14, 13),
    (15, 13),
    (16, 13),
    (17, 13),
    (18, 13),
    (22, 13),
    (23, 13),
    (24, 13),
    (32, 13),
    (11, 14),
    (1, 14),
    (2, 14),
    (3, 14),
    (4, 14),
    (5, 14),
    (6, 14),
    (7, 14),
    (8, 14),
    (12, 14),
    (13, 14),
    (23, 14),
    (32, 14),
    (0, 15),
    (1, 15),
    (8, 15),
    (9, 15),
    (10, 15),
    (11, 15),
    (23, 15),
    (25, 15),
    (29, 15),
    (30, 15),
    (31, 15),
    (32, 15),
    (0, 16),
    (9, 16),
    (18, 16),
    (19, 16),
    (20, 16),
    (21, 16),
    (22, 16),
    (23, 16),
    (25, 16),
    (29, 16),
    (0, 17),
    (9, 17),
    (18, 17),
    (25, 17),
    (29, 17),
    (0, 18),
    (9, 18),
    (18, 18),
    (25, 18),
    (29, 18),
    (0, 19),
    (9, 19),
    (10, 19),
    (11, 19),
    (12, 19),
    (13, 19),
    (14, 19),
    (16, 19),
    (17, 19),
    (18, 19),
    (25, 19),
    (26, 19),
    (27, 19),
    (28, 19),
    (29, 19),
    (0, 20),
    (3, 20),
    (14, 20),
    (15, 20),
    (16, 20),
    (18, 20),
    (25, 20),
    (0, 21),
    (3, 21),
    (4, 21),
    (18, 21),
    (25, 21),
    (0, 22),
    (3, 22),
    (4, 22),
    (5, 22),
    (18, 22),
    (25, 22),

    (0, 23),
    (3, 23),
    (4, 23),
    (5, 23),
    (6, 23),
    (18, 23),
    (25, 23),
    (0, 24),
    (2, 24),
    (3, 24),
    (4, 24),
    (5, 24),
    (6, 24),
    (7, 24),
    (8, 24),
    (9, 24),
    (10, 24),
    (11, 24),
    (12, 24),
    (13, 24),
    (14, 24),
    (15, 24),
    (16, 24),
    (17, 24),
    (18, 24),
    (25, 24),
    (0, 25),
    (18, 25),
    (25, 25),
    (0, 26),
    (18, 26),
    (25, 26),
    (0, 27),
    (18, 27),
    (25, 27),
    (0, 28),
    (18, 28),
    (25, 28),
    (0, 29),
    (1, 29),
    (2, 29),
    (3, 29),
    (4, 29),
    (5, 29),
    (6, 29),
    (7, 29),
    (8, 29),
    (9, 29),
    (10, 29),
    (11, 29),
    (12, 29),
    (13, 29),
    (14, 29),
    (15, 29),
    (16, 29),
    (18, 29),
    (25, 29),
    (13, 30),
    (18, 30),
    (25, 30),
    (13, 31),
    (18, 31),
    (25, 31),
    (13, 32),
    (18, 32),
    (25, 32),
    (13, 33),
    (16, 33),
    (17, 33),
    (18, 33),
    (25, 33),
    (13, 34),
    (15, 34),
    (18, 34),
    (25, 34),
    (13, 35),
    (18, 35),
    (25, 35),
    (13, 36),
    (14, 36),
    (15, 36),
    (18, 36),
    (25, 36),
    (15, 37),
    (18, 37),
    (25, 37),
    (15, 38),
    (18, 38),
    (19, 38),
    (20, 38),
    (21, 38),
    (23, 38),
    (24, 38),
    (25, 38),
    (15, 39),
    (23, 39),
    (15, 40),
    (23, 40),
    (15, 41),
    (16, 41),
    (17, 41),
    (18, 41),
    (19, 41),
    (20, 41),
    (21, 41),
    (22, 41),
    (23, 41)
]
Spikes = [
    (33, 9),
    (34, 9),
    (26, 18),
    (27, 18),
    (28, 18),
    (3, 19),
    (15, 19),
    (4, 20),
    (5, 21),
    (6, 22),
    (7, 23),
    (9, 23),
    (10, 23),
    (11, 23),
    (12, 23),
    (13, 23),
    (3, 28),
    (4, 28),
    (5, 28),
    (7, 28),
    (9, 28),
    (11, 28),
    (13, 28),
    (15, 28),
    (15, 33),
    (19, 37),
    (20, 37),
    (21, 37),
    (23, 37),
    (24, 37),
    (16,40)
]
Finish_Point = (17, 23)
Player = [11, 18]
Jump_Height = 0
CELLS = [(x, y) for y in range(Y) for x in range(X)]
main_sc=0

while True:
    if main_sc==0:
        Start_Menu_1()
    else:
        Start_Menu_2()  
    aa=msvcrt.getch().decode("ASCII")
    if aa == "B":
        print("Runnner............")
        input()
    if aa=="w" and main_sc!=0:
        Start_Menu_1()
        main_sc=0
    if aa=="s" and main_sc!=1:
        Start_Menu_2()
        main_sc=1
    if aa==" " :
        if main_sc == 0:
            os.system('cls')
            while True:
                print_game()

                Jump()
                
                Move, _ = timedInput("", timeout=0.05)
                if Move == "d":
                    Movement("d")
                if Move == "a":
                    Movement("a")
                if Move == "w" and (Player[0], Player[1]+1) in Border and Jump_Height == 0:
                    b = randint(0, 2)
                    if b != 1:
                        Jump_Height = 3
                    else:
                        Jump_Height = 6
                if Move == "p" :
                    break
                if (Player[0], Player[1]+1) in Spikes or (Player[0], Player[1]+1-1) in Spikes:
                    if Jump_Height == 0 :    
                        Lose_Menu()
                        break
                #sys.stdout.write('\x1b[43A')


        else:
            exit()
    Player = [11, 18]
```

You can check out this code.

Check out line no. 25 this is where i'm trying to move cursor to the beginning.
but it only moves the cursor half way through.

Comment: the cmd is some how saveing first few lines so we are not able to move cursor to most top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks like moving the cursor around the terminal generally involves ansi escape sequence. To move the cursor to the top left corner, print to stdout the escape sequence `\x1b[H`. Or to simply clear the screen, use `\x1b[2J`.

So you may need something like `sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")`

More on escape sequence:

- [ANSI Escape](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)
- [VT100 terminal manual](https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/contents.html)

Answer (score 0):

the cmd is some how saving first few lines so we are not able to move cursor to most top left corner.

you can use the code "\x1b[3J" to remove saved lines .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).